# Why does compiler tries to pass a pointer to reference rather than pointer in this code snippet?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, virtual, pass-by-reference

I have 5 files:

- `ExecutionStrategyInterface.h`
- `ExecutorInterface.h`
- `TaskCollectionInterface.h`
- `TaskExecutor.h`
- `TaskExecutor.cpp`.

`TaskExecutor` implements the following member method:

```
void TaskExecutor::execute(TaskCollectionInterface* tci, const ExecutionStrategyInterface& es) {
    es.execute(tci);
}
```

At compile time, the compiler calls a member method with a parameter of type pointer to a reference
(i.e: `mylib::core::TaskCollectionInterface*&`).

```
TaskExecutor.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void mylib::core::TaskExecutor::execute(mylib::core::TaskCollectionInterface*, const mylib::core::ExecutionStrategyInterface&)’:
TaskExecutor.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘mylib::core::ExecutionStrategyInterface::execute(mylib::core::TaskCollectionInterface*&) const’
./././ExecutionStrategyInterface.h:24: note: candidates are: virtual void mylib::core::ExecutionStrategyInterface::execute(TaskCollectionInterface*) const
make: *** [TaskExecutor.o] Error 1
```

**Can anyone explain me what is happening here please ?**

---

**Classes:**

**ExecutionStrategyInterface.h**

```
#ifndef _EXECUTIONSTRATEGYINTERFACE_H_
#define _EXECUTIONSTRATEGYINTERFACE_H_

class TaskCollectionInterface;

namespace mylib { namespace core {

/**
 *  Interface for executing a strategy.
 */
class ExecutionStrategyInterface {
 public:
    /**
     * Executes a strategy
     */
    virtual void execute(TaskCollectionInterface* tci) const = 0;
};

}} // namespaces

#endif // _EXECUTIONSTRATEGYINTERFACE_H_
```

**TaskCollectionInterface.h**

```
#ifndef _TASKCOLLECTIONINTERFACE_H_
#define _TASKCOLLECTIONINTERFACE_H_

#include "./ExecutionStrategyInterface.h"

namespace mylib { namespace core {

/**
 *  Interface for a collection of tasks.
 */
class TaskCollectionInterface {
 public:
    ~TaskCollectionInterface();
};

}} // namespaces

#endif // _TASKCOLLECTIONINTERFACE_H_
```

**ExecutorInterface.h**

```
#ifndef _EXECUTORINTERFACE_H_
#define _EXECUTORINTERFACE_H_

class ExecutionStrategyInterface;
class TaskCollectionInterface;

#include "./ExecutionStrategyInterface.h"
#include "./TaskCollectionInterface.h"

namespace mylib { namespace core {

/**
 *  Interface for an executor.
 */
class ExecutorInterface {
 public:
    virtual void execute(TaskCollectionInterface* tci, const ExecutionStrategyInterface& es) = 0;
    ~ExecutorInterface();
};

}} // namespaces

#endif // _EXECUTORINTERFACE_H_
```

**TaskExecutor.h**

```
#ifndef _TASKEXECUTOR_H_
#define _TASKEXECUTOR_H_

#include "./ExecutorInterface.h"

class TaskCollectionInterface;
class ExecutionStrategyInterface;

namespace mylib { namespace core {

/**
 *  Task Runner.
 */
class TaskExecutor: public ExecutorInterface {
 public:
    virtual void execute(TaskCollectionInterface* tci, const ExecutionStrategyInterface& es) = 0;
};

}} // namespaces

#endif // _TASKEXECUTOR_H_
```

**TaskExecutor.cpp**

```
#include "./TaskExecutor.h"
#include "./ExecutionStrategyInterface.h"
#include "./TaskCollectionInterface.h"

namespace mylib { namespace core {

void TaskExecutor::execute(TaskCollectionInterface* tci, const ExecutionStrategyInterface& es) {
    es.execute(tci);
}

}} // namespaces
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is confusing because you are forward-declaring the class outside the namespace, so you are ending up with two different classes with the same name.  You'll want something like this instead:

```
namespace mylib {
  namespace core {
    class TaskCollectionInterface;
    class ExecutionStrategyInterface {
      .
      .
      .
    };
  }
}
```

The way you have it now, your execute method is taking a pointer to ::TaskCollectionInterface instead of mylib::core::TaskCollectionInterface.

Answer (score 0):

When gcc says `type&`, it's just its shorthand for saying that you are passing an lvalue so that you know that functions taking a non-const reference are viable candidates.

The problem that you have is that you have declared the method as taking a `::TaskCollectionInterface`, but the error message indicates that you are attempting to pass a `::mylib::core::TaskCollectionInterface`.

You have a declaration of `::mylib::core::TaskCollectionInterface` in `TaskCollectionInterface.h` that masks the declaration of `::TaskCollectionInterface` in the namespace `mylib::core`.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are passing a pointer `TaskCollectionInterface* tci` to the `ExecutionStrategyInterface::execute` method, while it wants a reference. So you have to dereference that pointer when passing it to that function:

```
void TaskExecutor::execute(TaskCollectionInterface* tci, const ExecutionStrategyInterface& es) {
    es.execute(*tci);
}
```